# Sonata slow to start went inside it ran for around a 1/2 hr went outside and it stalled out,

Tags: starting, hyundai, sonata

Started Car went inside and returned 1/2 later its 5 degrees out the car stalled, the blower was still on and the car was still warm. All dashboard lights were on and so was the TPMS light with a yellow traingle. Tried restating the car and nothing.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! When you say "nothing" ... what do you mean?

Comment: What does the fuel gauge say?

Answer (score 0):

Cars don't like the cold and it could have died shortly after you started it. If it died and it was sitting for nearly 30 minutes with the dash lights on (possibly head lights too if it was dark and they are automatic) and the blower running, it probably drained the battery. I would jump it and see if it will stay running. My guess is it just died from the extreme cold and battery was drained while sitting there.